# Remove Bookmarks from pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, hyperlink, bookmarks

Hi
I have prepared a pdf using latex where i have given email addresses in that tex file. When i click the email links in pdf, it pops up with a email client. How can i remove the link not popping up. Basically i want to remove all these links/bookmarks? ( i am not using hyperref package also)
Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe your PDF-viewer automatically recognizes mail-adresses?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), the hyperlink (email address) is detected automatically by the PDF viewer. You can de-activate this in Adobe Acrobat via *Edit* > *Preferences* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and deselecting "Create links from URLs" under the "General" category:

[image]

Comment: The OP's problem may be that he wants to suppress the behaviour in everyone's reader, not just her own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the email addresses non-obvious to the machine, I'd suggest that you code them in a format similar to this:

```
<firstname> (dot) <lastname> (at) <somewhere> (dot) <net>
```

An example:

> kaja (dot) programmer (at) stackoverflow (dot) com